# Retrieve class parameter using a string in Dart

Tags: string, class, oop, dart

Let's say that I have a class in Dart that looks like this:

```
class Hello {

  final name;

  Hello({this.name});

}
```

I could create an instance of this class using:

```
var x = new Hello(name: "General Kenobi");
```

In Javascript, I could retrieve the name property with syntax like this:

```
console.log(x["name"]);
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent in Dart? I.e

```
print(x["name"]);
```

I've looked at the docs and can't find anything, would appreciate help from someone who knows. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a method, which converts a class to `Map` and overload `[]` operator:

```dart
class Hello {
  final name;

  Hello({this.name});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {'name': name};

  operator [](String field) => toMap()[field];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't know about that operator syntax, which is pretty nice. Thanks for the help.

Comment: srl there is no other way? I created a class that I later save in a database. Before doing this it needs to be converted to a string and when I get it, I convert it back to the class. Now, I need to read a dynamic param and I also have to convert the whole thing to a Map again?